# Update ModalDialog progress bar from async await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, modal-dialog, async-await

I am trying to understand better how to update ProgressBar Value using async and await.

I can update the progress bar value using async if progress bar is on UI main thread. But i am having modal dialog window which contains progress bar within it and this modal dialog pops up when I click on a button.

Now I want to update value of this progress bar from Async method.

How to update modal dialog progress bar from async method?

P.S - I don't want to use BackgroundWorker.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running a WPF app you can do that by calling the current dispatcher

```
private void PushOnUIThread(Action action)
        {
            if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                action();
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
            }
        }
```

Then you can call

```
PushOnUIThread(()=> progressBar.Value = 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for can be accomplished with `IProgress<T>`. `IProgress<T>` and the default implementation `Progress<T>` is the way to report progress from another context.

Have a look at: [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)

And a sample from the post by @StephenCleary

```
public async void StartProcessingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // The Progress<T> constructor captures our UI context,
  //  so the lambda will be run on the UI thread.
  var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
  {
    textBox1.Text = percent + "%";
  });

  // DoProcessing is run on the thread pool.
  await Task.Run(() => DoProcessing(progress));
  textBox1.Text = "Done!";
}

public void DoProcessing(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100); // CPU-bound work
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report(i);
  }
}
```